# NodeJS missing from Configure System page

Tags: node.js, jenkins

I'm using Jenkins 2.190.2, and I have the NodeJS Plugin v. 1.3.4 installed.

I can see the "Provide Node & npm bin/folder to PATH" option, in my individual job configure pages. There's a "NodeJS Installation" dropdown, with one entry - "NodeJS v10.16.0".

But when I go to the Manage Jenkins/Configure System page, I'd expect to see a NodeJS section, where I could specify which NodeJS Installations I wanted available in Jenkins. And there's nothing there.

This is no NodeJS section in /configure.

I've uninstalled and reinstalled the NodeJS Plugin, and it's still not there.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

OK - just plain stupid.

Plugin configuration isn't in /configure, anymore, it's in /configureTools.